# android change brightness setting from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, settings, brightness

I have an app that is installed on the system partition (Android 4.4.1 and 4.1.2). I need it to set the brightness of the screen according the battery level. So, I register on `Application` class a `BroadcastReceiver` that listens to `Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` intent to check the battery status.

I've seen many answers about how to do it on an `Activity` and even on a `Service` using an fake `Activity`. I could use the `Service` - `Activity` approach but I don't want to start an activity just to apply the brightness setting to the `WindowManager`.

This is what I currently have:

```
    ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
    int currentBrightness = Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, -1);
    int newBrightness = -1;

    // Set brightness according to the battery level
    if (batteryPercentage > BatteryUtils.BATTERY_SAFE_LEVEL
            && currentBrightness != BRIGHTNESS_HIGH) {
        newBrightness = BRIGHTNESS_HIGH;
    } else if (batteryPercentage <= BatteryUtils.BATTERY_SAFE_LEVEL
            && batteryPercentage > BatteryUtils.BATTERY_LOW_LEVEL
            && currentBrightness != BRIGHTNESS_NORMAL) {
        newBrightness = BRIGHTNESS_NORMAL;
    } else if (batteryPercentage <= BatteryUtils.BATTERY_LOW_LEVEL
            && currentBrightness != BRIGHTNESS_LOW) {
        newBrightness = BRIGHTNESS_LOW;
    }

    if (newBrightness != -1) {
        Settings.System.putInt(contentResolver, Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE, Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_MANUAL);
        Settings.System.putInt(contentResolver, Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, newBrightness);
        Log.v(context.getString(R.string.app_name), "BatteryReceiver: setting brightness to " + newBrightness + "("+ batteryPercentage+ "%, " + plugged +")");
    }
```

As you might imagine, the brightness setting is changed correctly -if I reboot the device the new brightness setting will be applied next time the device reboot- but it's not applied immediatly.

Is there another way of applying the setting immediatly without having to start an activity? Maybe an API that my **system app** can use?